# Is there any possibility for Root scss has to load in component while doing unit testing with karma & Jasmine

Tags: angular

Is there any possibility to load scss from root into component while doing unit testing? All the styles I have written in root styles.scss file.

But, When I am doing unit testing only scss in that component is loading so styles are not effecting which I have mentioned in root styles.scss file.

So I have to include that root styles.scss file while unit tests are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is possible to include your root css file in Karma config, like so:

```
files: [
  { pattern: './src/root.scss', watched: true,  included: true, served: true }
],
```

Please note, that this will include the css file to all your tests.

But, the only valuable advice would be to move all required css from your root css file into component, which is 100% angular way. You having the problems just because you neglecting the official approach...